# IndexOutOfBoundsException for LinkedList

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to set the text of a text field to a string based on the value selected in a `JList`.

- `JList` = `list`
- `LinkedList<WordPair>` = `wordpair_list`
- `WordPair` contains `wordA` and `wordB`

If anyone can explain to me why this doesn't work I would be forever in your debt. there is obviously a lot more code in this program, but `stackoverflow` seems to think my text to code ratio is disproportionate. if you personally want the rest of the code I'd be glad to send it to you if you are up for the challenge.

```
public void showTranslation(){
    int i = wordpair_list.indexOf(list.getSelectedValue());
    textField.setText(wordpair_list.get(i).getWordB());
}

public Dictionary(Object o){ 
    if (o instanceof String){ 
        String filename = (String) o; 
        File file = new File(filename); 
        Scanner sc = null; 

        try { 
            sc = new Scanner(file); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        while (sc.hasNextLine()){ 
           words.add(new WordPair(sc.nextLine())); 
        } 
    } 
}

public WordPair(String arg0) { 
    arg0.trim(); 
    int equalsIndex = arg0.indexOf("="); 
    this.wordA = arg0.substring(0, equalsIndex-1); 
    this.wordB = arg0.substring(equalsIndex+1); 
}
```

Comment: Post your exception, full call trace and the part of code that it points to.

Comment: It seems like a `Map<String, String>` would suit your purposes better than a `List<WordPair>`.

Comment: 'code'  
      public Dictionary(Object o){
  if (o instanceof String){
  String filename = (String) o;
  
  File file = new File(filename);
  Scanner sc = null;
  
  try {
   sc = new Scanner(file);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  while (sc.hasNextLine()){
   words.add(new WordPair(sc.nextLine()));
  }
  }
 }
and...

       public WordPair(String arg0){
  arg0.trim();
  int equalsIndex = arg0.indexOf("=");
  this.wordA = arg0.substring(0, equalsIndex-1);
  this.wordB = arg0.substring(equalsIndex+1);
 }

Comment: i can't seem to get it to post the code in code format, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wordpair_list` does not contain whatever `list.getSelectedValue()` returns.  Note that the [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method will return `-1` when the specified object is not contained within the list.

You can confirm this by printing/logging the value of `i`.

In terms of fixing the code, if `wordpair_list` actually *did* contain `list.getSelectedValue()`, your code could be more concisely written as:

```
public void showTranslation(){
    textField.setText(list.getSelectedValue().getWordB());
}
```

But since that value is not in the list, you'll have to try some other approach.  One possibility is that you have confused your types, and are looking in the `wordpair_list` for an object of an incompatible type.  Another possibility is that you need to override `equals()` (and as a consequence, also `hashCode()`) so that your `indexOf()` lookup succeeds.

More info on that last bit here:  [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: so, i debugged it using various sysouts, and learned that i was trying to find an element of an object in a linkedlist of objects. so when checking for the indexof the selected element, i need the index of where that word came from. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just by the code you provided, but if wordpar_list contains only 2 elements (wordA and wordB), the output of list.getSelectedValue() can only be 0 or 1. I would try to print out (or debug) to see what list.getSelectedValue() is giving you, but it probably isn't 0 or 1 as you would expect.

Hope that helps!

Comment: wordpair_list is a linked list in which each element contains a wordA and a wordB. the linked list type is WordPair which is a class I made to contain both words.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case where you could use a debugger. Or insert a bunch of System.out.println() to print out some of the local values.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to debug this code, print out whatever is returned from `indexOf()`
second, you should probably not use `LinkedList` but rather `ArrayList` for a best practice.

another thing, you'll probably have to cast `wordpair_list.get(i)` into `WordPair` or whatever that object is.

Comment: how could i change that indexof statement to get the index of the JList 'list' when JList doesn't have an indexof operation?